# Spring multiple autowired beans modeling

Tags: java, spring

I would like to code properly multiple executors using Spring, but need to load them only when it's necessary and required, bellow an example to explain clearly the needs.

```java
@Component
public class Executor[A-Z] {
    @Autowired
    Dep[A-Z] dep[A-Z];

    @Autowired
    Dep[A-Z] dep[A-Z];

   /**
    example :
    DepA depA;
    DepC depC;
   */
   
  public void execute() {
    // method body
  }
}
```

I have multiple Executors from A to Z (ExecutorA,..... ExecutorZ)

Those executors are used in a service class MyService :

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    ExecutorA executorA;

    //.....

    @Autowired
    ExecutorZ executorZ;
   
  public void launchExecutor() {
    if ( conditionA ) {
        executorA.execute();
     } else if( confitionB ) {
         executorB.execute();
     } else {
         executorZ.execute();
     }

  }
}
```

In the example above on MyService class i have to load all Executors at once, whereas may few of them could be used.

What is the best way to optimize numbers of beans loaded in Spring IoC container in this example ? Is there a manner to create Executor[A-Z] instance on demand based on conditions ?

Thank you

Comment: You might need to look into command pattern, have a look at the article https://medium.com/codex/how-i-implemented-command-pattern-in-spring-boot-870c1f2c73b0

Comment: When they implement an `CommonInterface` you can inject them in a `List<CommonInterface> executors;`

Comment: Oh and please use constructor injection, that way your dependencies are clearer and your service will be better testable.